# Recording a cell select

Tags: excel, vba

The recorder won't pick up any selection of a cell.

It will record selection of a range, row or column.

I recently switched from Home to Business Excel, but I cannot imagine this is the cause.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot explain why your Macro Recorder does not record your range selection, that is abnormal behaviour.  Single cell selection, however, is not recorded unless you do something else with that selection.

To select a cell, use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select`

To select a range of cells, use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B2").Select`

Replace the "Sheet1" with the name of your sheet, and the cell references with the cells you are interested in.

As other users have mentioned in the comments, consider avoid using the `.Select` method for ranges and cells.  While you are learning, it may be a useful tool to clearly show the steps used by the program.  However, as you progress into larger and more complicated codes, repeated use of the `.Select` method will really slow down your programs' performance.

Answer (score 0):

Start Macro recording. Select a range of two cells.  Click on one of the two cells.  Stop recording.  Look at the recorded macro.  The code for selecting a single cell should be apparent after a small amount of study.

But to be honest, you shouldn't be writing code that operates on 'Selected' ranges or cells.  Instead you should be working on a range/cell reference.  Much better in the long run.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. I can select the range of two cells, but not, then, the single cell. I mean, the range records, but not the single cell selection.

I know I won't be needing to do absolute references, but I'm starting from basics. As I work through tutorials they all start with selecting a cell!

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong.  Select the range, Move the mouse away from the range, then click in the first cell of the selected range.  Can you post a link to the youtube video so we can let you know if it is suitable for its intended purpose.

Comment: Well, I don't think I'm doing anything wrong. Here's a link to a quick screen capture of a macro recording session, showing both the sheet and the VBA workbook.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Iwu5cg4Fne7Q3NNI-eycANzcDZKWeyhY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, that takes too long to come up.  Instead try Start recording, right click on any cell stop recording.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean that it takes too long to come up. You mean the video file takes too long to begin?
That is more or less what I did before. I've done another screen capture video. I selected three different cells, which did not register with macro recording. Then I selected a range, which did.   Thanks for any help you can give.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wu4BcIAve6z291P_ZiBcghxPhIjgnLnR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It means that when I click on play and after five minutes  I've still got a blank screen I give up.